# Laravel pretend is not showing cc mail address

Tags: php, email, laravel, laravel-4

I had change `pretend` as `true` in mail config. please check http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/mail#mail-and-local-development

Now log is showing to address like this.

```
[2014-11-22 17:12:49] production.INFO: Pretending to mail message to: dinukathilanga@gmail.com, bbelekkaya@gmail.com [] []
```

But i need debug cc emails also. How can i do it?

This is my code.

```
Mail::send($view, $data, function($message) use ($to, $cc, $subject)
{
    foreach ($to as $toUser) {
        $message->to($toUser['email'], $toUser['first_name'] . ' ' . $toUser['last_name']);
    }

    foreach ($cc as $ccUser) {
        $message->cc($ccUser['email'], $ccUser['first_name'] . ' ' . $ccUser['last_name']);
    }

    $message->subject($subject);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Allow me to be frank here. I am new to **Laravel**, but I will try my best to explain this.

I do know how to debug email platforms though, the easiest process is by doing it through **C**.

I will try to be succint as possible.

Firstly, try using the **laravel-debugbar** (the latest version is 4).
This is an application that is capable of filtering the **PHP Debug Bar**.
By using this application you will be able to attach and edit output functions (here is the link for more information: [Debug bar](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar).

If this won't work, try debugging through **C**.

Fristly, you will compile the **C** program by inserting the debug option, *option -g*.
Afterwards, you'll launch the gdb into the platform.
Thirdly, you'll break the point in the **C** program, specifically, insert the *break line_number* function.
After that, you'll print the variable values in the gdp debugger.

For instance, you'll type commands such as *print j* and *(gdp) p i* (I will post the website where I've got this information from; it will give you a more broader walkthrough).

There are various operation for this process.
I strongly advise you visiting:[Debug C program using gdb](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/03/debug-c-program-using-gdb/). Hope this helped.

Comment: thanks for reply. But i just need to use pretend value in mail config.

Comment: You mean you need to find the value/function to insert into the encryption, right?

Answer (score 0):

Create a new class named ExtendedMailer for the sake of this example and save the file somewhere the autoloader is able to find it. Depending on where you put the file, you may need to run `composer dump-autoload` once you've saved it.

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Mail\Mailer;

class ExtendedMailer extends Mailer
{
    protected function logMessage($message)
    {
        parent::logMessage($message);

        $emails = implode(', ', array_keys((array) $message->getCc()));

        $this->logger->info("Pretending to mail message to: {$emails}");
    }
}
```

Create a new service provider, somewhere your application is able to load classes. As above, you may need to run `composer dump-autoload`

The below code simply extends the original MailServiceProvider but allows us to bind a different class to in the IoC, you'll notice the `new ExtendedMailer`; the class we created earlier. Obviously if you namespaced the class, reflect that change here.

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider;

class ExtendedMailServiceProvider extends MailServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register the service provider.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $me = $this;

        $this->app->bindShared('mailer', function($app) use ($me)
        {
            $me->registerSwiftMailer();

            // Once we have create the mailer instance, we will set a container instance
            // on the mailer. This allows us to resolve mailer classes via containers
            // for maximum testability on said classes instead of passing Closures.
            $mailer = new ExtendedMailer(
                $app['view'], $app['swift.mailer'], $app['events']
            );

            $this->setMailerDependencies($mailer, $app);

            // If a "from" address is set, we will set it on the mailer so that all mail
            // messages sent by the applications will utilize the same "from" address
            // on each one, which makes the developer's life a lot more convenient.
            $from = $app['config']['mail.from'];

            if (is_array($from) && isset($from['address']))
            {
                $mailer->alwaysFrom($from['address'], $from['name']);
            }

            // Here we will determine if the mailer should be in "pretend" mode for this
            // environment, which will simply write out e-mail to the logs instead of
            // sending it over the web, which is useful for local dev environments.
            $pretend = $app['config']->get('mail.pretend', false);

            $mailer->pretend($pretend);

            return $mailer;
        });
    }
}
```

In your config/app.php, you'll find a line which looks like

```
'Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider',
```

You'll need to comment it out and add a line as below

```
'ExtendedMailServiceProvider',
```

What this does is replace the mailer which Laravel knows about with the one you've just created. The one you've just created is the same as the default one as it merely extends it, and adds functionality to the logMessage function.

Comment: i improve the question with a link. I just want use pretend config. No need use too many code for check cc values.

Comment: I understand that you want to use the pretend value. You'll notice that the method within the framework which outputs the data to the log simply doesn't interact with the Cc emails at all. See `/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Mail/Mailer.php` and look for the method `logMessage()`. The reason the above code is necessary is because it allows you to extend the framework, and add the logging of CC emails to the method